# Map Caps Lock to AltGr and Escape - why does setxkbmap silence xcape daemon?

Tags: xkb, setxkbmap, capslock, xcape

I'm on a 20.04 Ubuntu machine.

I've been trying to use a combination of `setxkmap` and `xcape` to map AltGr and escape onto my caps-lock key, where a *quick key press* acts as **escape** and a *longer key press* acts as **AltGr**.

I believed the desired behavior could be achieved by executing the following:

```
$ setxkbmap -option lv3:caps_switch
$ xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape' -t 300
```

Once the setxkbmap command is executed however, the xcape process/daemon no longer makes caps-lock act as escape when tapped.
I'm not entirely sure why since the **xcape process is still running**, so I might just simply be oblivious to how setxkbmap works (I tried executing the commands in a different order, with the same result).

How would I go about achieving the desired behavior?

Why does setxkbmap 'silence' the xcape daemon regardless of whether I execute xcape before/after executing the setxkbmap command?

Answer (score 0):

`setxkbmap` has nothing to do with your issue, the documentation for [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) mentions (enphasis mine) :

> > `-t <timeout ms>`
>
> If you hold a key longer than this **timeout**, xcape **will not generate a key event**. Default is 500 ms.

Comment: I am aware of the timeout option, however that does not really address my issue since the behavior I'm after *inculdes* the ```xcape``` timeout. I've tested even longer timeout periods (lets say I wasn't tapping quickly enough to generate the key event), but after executing ```setxkbmap -option lv3:caps_switch``` the caps lock key **exclusively** acts as AltGr, even with the xcape daemon running in the background. This is not an issue of xcape: if I reset setxkbmap by executing ```setxkbmap -option```, the caps-lock key now seems to have desired effects of a timedout escape caused by xcape.

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior could be achieved by executing the following commands:

```
# create daemons that map Caps Lock with AltGr and Escape (escape is timed out) 
$ xcape -e "#66=Escape" -t 300
$ xcape -e "#66=ISO_Level3_Shift"
# changes current X keyboard session configuration
$ setxkbmap -option lv3:caps_switch
```